# Starting chat on a hidden community leaks network profile

Tags: bug, chat, hidden-communities

I've hidden one of my communities, but when a comments co-conversationalist started a chat session, it was started on the network-wide https://chat.stackexchange.com, and my network identity was revealed there, not the one that's active on that specific site.

This means hiding does not work as advertised and is easily overcome.

Comment: "This means hiding does not work as advertised and is easily overcome. " Well, yes. That's always been the case; it used to be much, much worse, though.

Comment: This probably isn't something we'll ever fix because you only have one chat profile for the entire network, rather than multiple profiles that can just be hidden from each other.

Comment: @animuson stop yer false advertising, then.